# Multiplatform way to convert between std::string and std::wstring

Tags: c++, boost

I am currently using the methods `MultiByteToWideChar` and `WideCharToMultiByte` of the Windows API to convert between `std::string` and `std::wstring`.

I am 'multiplatforming' my code removing Windows dependencies, so I would like to know alternative to the methods above. Concretely, using **boost** will be great. Which methods may I use? Here is the code I am currently using:

```
const std::wstring Use::stow(const std::string& str)
{
    if (str.empty()) return L"";
    int size_needed = MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0);
    std::wstring wstrTo( size_needed, 0 );
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed);
    return wstrTo;
}

const std::string Use::wtos(const std::wstring& wstr)
{
    if (wstr.empty()) return "";
    int size_needed = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    std::string strTo( size_needed, 0 );
    WideCharToMultiByte                  (CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL);
    return strTo;
}
```

Comment: How about the standard [`std::mbstowcs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/mbstowcs) and [`std::wcstombs`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/multibyte/wcstombs)?

Comment: It's probably more complicated than just finding a conversion function, see [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: Oops!! I didn't know about that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically using the `<cstdlib>` you can get away with a similar implementation to what you already have, [as mentioned by Joachim Pileborg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20375049/multiplatform-way-to-convert-between-stdstring-and-stdwstring/20376525#comment30419605_20375049). As long as you have set the locale to whatever you want it to be (for example: `setlocale( LC_ALL, "en_US.utf8" );`

`MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), NULL, 0)` => `mbstowcs(nullptr, data(str), size(str))`

`MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8, 0, &str[0], (int)str.size(), &wstrTo[0], size_needed)` => `mbstowcs(data(wstrTo), data(str), size(str))`

`WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), NULL, 0, NULL, NULL)` => `wcstombs(nullptr, data(wstr), size(wstr))`

`WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, &wstr[0], (int)wstr.size(), &strTo[0], size_needed, NULL, NULL)` => `wcstombs(data(strTo), data(wstr), size(wstr))`

**EDIT:**

[c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) [requires strings to be allocated contiguously](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30977974/2642059), which may be important if you are compiling cross-platform as previous standards did *not* require `string` to be allocated contiguously. Previously calling `&str[0]`, `&strTo[0]`, `&wstr[0]`, or `&wstrTo[0]` could have caused problems.
Since [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is now the accepted standard, I've improved my suggested substitutions to use [`data`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data) rather than dereferencing the front of the strings.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, it has worked! Do you think I can get memory errors using this approach? I am worried about memory allocation.

Comment: Why not call `str.c_str()` instead of using `&str[0]`? It will certainly be continuous.

Comment: Yes, I believe @Julien's suggestion will work for the source string provided `c_str()` works with `std::wstring` however it won't work for the destination string. For a destination string my initial thought would be that you should temporarily allocate a vector and then copy into a string. So something like this in wtos: `std::vector< char > temp( size_needed, '\0' ); std::wcstombs( &*temp.begin(), wstr.c_str(), wstr.size() ); std::string strTo( size_needed, '\0' ); std::copy( strTo.begin(), strTo.end(), temp.begin() );` This would probably make a great follow up question!

Comment: This is a great way to do this for common code across platforms. If it still needs to run on Windows you'll need to add the _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS preprocessor macro. Otherwise it'll complain that you aren't using the Windows-specific mbstowcs_s

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it looks like you are using utf-8 encoding. For working with utf-8 take a look at  UTF8-CPP at http://utfcpp.sourceforge.net/ which is a header only library

Look at the utf8to32 function. (Note that on Windows wchar_t is 16 bits, on other platforms such as linux it is usually 32bits)

Answer (score -1):

```
const std::wstring Use::stow(const std::string &s)
{
    return std::wstring(s.begin(), s.end());
}

const std::string Use::wtos(const std::wstring &ws)
{
    return std::string(ws.begin(), ws.end());
}
```

Comment: Do not do this, this will do horrible things with strings that contain non-ascii characters and will likely yield invalid unicode strings.