# C++11 Allocation Requirement on Strings

Tags: c++, string, c++11, memory, standards

I had heard that C++11 was going to require `string`s to be allocated in contiguous memory. I even thought I saw a stack overflow question on it, but I can't seem to find it.

I know that in practice both gcc and Visual Studio do allocate `string`s contiguously, I'm just asking as to the standard's requirements.

Comment: Do you mean the underlying `string` structure and its dynamic buffer would be contiguous? How would that work if the string needed to grow beyond its initial allocation?

Comment: @JonathanPotter The `string` could exist in a linked list for example? This would mean that calls to `string::data` and `string::c_str` would have to allocate temporary space. I just want to know what's required by the standard.

Comment: perhaps you were looking for [Is it reasonable to use std::basic_string<t> as a contiguous buffer when targeting C++03?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2256160/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour That's a great link! I would have said, that was where I read his but I hadn't up-voted the anything on the page... so maybe not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Section 21.4.1.5 of the 2011 standard states:

> The char-like objects in a `basic_string` object shall be stored
>   contiguously. That is, for any `basic_string` object `s`, the identity
>   `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` shall hold for all values of
>   `n` such that `0 <= n < s.size()`.

The two parts of the identity expression are

1. Take the `begin()` iterator, advance by `n`, then dereference and take the address of the resulting element.
2. Take the `begin()` iterator, dereference and take the address of the resulting element. Add `n` to this pointer.

Since both are required to be identical, this enforces contiguous storage; that is, the iterator cannot move over any non-contiguous storage without violating this requirement.

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thank you, I'll accept shortly. It seems like this requirement *wasn't* in-place prior to C++11, but maybe I'm losing my mind.

Comment: @JonathanMee Correct. The wording of the C++03 standard does not specify this constraint, and the wording of the sections on `c_str()` and `data()` imply that implementations may need to copy data around to make a contiguous block for those purposes (the requirement that the program doesn't modify it, or re-use the pointer after modifying operations on the string, for instance). Having said that, I don't know of any implementation that *doesn't* store strings contiguously...