# Why Doesn't string::data() Provide a Mutable char*?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, containers, c-strings

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) `array`, `string`, and `vector` all got the `data` method which:

> Returns pointer to the underlying array serving as element storage. The pointer is such that range [`data()`; `data() + size()`) is always a valid range, even if the container is empty.
>   [[Source](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)]

This method is provided in a mutable and `const` version for all applicable containers, for example:

```
T* vector<T>::data();
const T* vector<T>::data() const;
```

All applicable containers, that is, except `string` which [only provides the `const` version](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data):

```
const char* string::data() const;
```

What happened here? Why did `string` get shortchanged, when `char* string::data()` would be so helpful?

Comment: It has been discussed and It's recorded as an issue, details [here](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-active.html#2391).

Comment: It does: `&s[0]`, for non-empty strings.

Comment: I think that if you need to modify the string via `data`, you probably are looking for `vector<char>`, instead. There're some exceptions, though.

Comment: @black I have used `vector<char>` extensively and regretted it every time, that I subsequently copy the characters back into a `string`. What I actually want is a `string` with a modifiable buffer.

Comment: @Alper This is the best answer by far. Would you be willing to write this up?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are std::vector::data and std::string::data different?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7518732/why-are-stdvectordata-and-stdstringdata-different)

Comment: @JonathanMee `std::string` *does* have a modifiable buffer. The issue mentioned by Alper is just that it has inconsistent naming compared to other standard library containers.

Comment: @M.M While it does have a modifiable buffer (circa C++11), it does not have an accessor for the buffer, so we're left creating our own: `&string::front()` or `&*string::begin()` and so on.

Comment: Huh? What's your definion of "accessor" if not "expression that accesses the buffer" ?

Comment: @M.M Maybe I should say "direct accessor" or something like that. That's the reason I want `char* string::data()` so I don't have to make a call on the `string` and then take the address of the return to get the buffer. I want a single call on the `string` to return it's modifiable buffer.

Comment: @Alper Welp, I added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34179377/2642059) that is essentially exactly what you said :( Hope you at least got the [Disciplined](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined) badge out of this.

Comment: You can simply (char*)mystring.data() .... not sure if this is good practice however =P

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon You're using a C-style cast there, which in C++ simplifies to (and would preferably be written as) a [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), wherein:  "Modifying a const object through a non-const access path and referring to a volatile object through a non-volatile glvalue results in undefined behavior." As such I believe we could say, "No, this is definitely not good practice."

Comment: @JonathanMee, I totally agree with you. What's scary is that I have seen this work in a code base that "undefined behavior" is very defined :(

Comment: @ChaoSXDemon One of the things that makes undefined behaviors so dangerous is they sometimes appear well behaved. `int* foo() { int result[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; return result; }` you may see this undefined behavior work for years until someone adjusts the order of events and `foo`'s stack frame is overwritten before its return is used. then suddenly you have undefined behavior that was "caused" by code totally unrelated to the problem. As someone who understands such things you have a responsibility to speak against them, or at a minimum not to propagate them by suggesting them in comments.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The short answer is that [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) does provide the [`char* string::data()` method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data). Which is vital for the similarly [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) [`data` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/data), thus to gain mutable access to the underlying C-String I can now do this:

```
auto foo = "lorem ipsum"s;

for(auto i = data(foo); *i != '\0'; ++i) ++(*i);
```

---

For historical purposes it's worth chronicling `string`'s development which [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17) is building upon: In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) access to `string`'s underlying buffer is made possible possible by a new requirement that it's elements are stored contiguously such that for any given `string s`:

> `&*(s.begin() + n) == &*s.begin() + n` for any `n` in [`0`, `s.size()`), or, equivalently, a pointer to `s[0]` can be passed to functions that expect a pointer to the first element of a `CharT[]` array.

Mutable access to this newly required underlying C-String was obtainable by various methods, for example: `&s.front()`, `&s[0]`, or `&*s.first()` But back to the original question which would avoid the burden of using one of these options: **Why hasn't access to `string`'s underlying buffer been provided in the form of `char* string::data()`?**

To answer that it is important to note that `T* array<T>::data()` and `T* vector<T>::data()` were an addition required by [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). No additional requirements were incurred by [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) against other contiguous containers such as `deque`. And there certainly wasn't an additional requirement for `string`, in fact the requirement that [`string` was contiguous](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30977974/2642059) was new to [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11). Before this [`const char* string::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) had existed. Though it explicitly was *not* guaranteed to be pointing to any underlying buffer, it was the only way to obtain a `const char*` from a `string`:

> The returned array is not required to be null-terminated.

This means that `string` was not "shortchanged" in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11)'s transition to `data` accessors, it simply was not included thus only the `const` `data` accesor that `string` previously possessed persisted. There are [naturally occurring examples in C++11's implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25403713/set-precision-and-clip-trailing-zeros-but-never-print-exponent) which necessitate writing directly to the underlying buffer of a `string`.

Answer (score 18):

I think this restriction comes from the (pre-2011) days where `std::basic_string` didn't have to store its internal buffer as a contiguous byte array.

While all the others (`std::vector` and such) had to store their elements as a contiguous sequence per the 2003 standard; so `data` could easily return mutable `T*`, because there was no problem with iterations, etc.

If `std::basic_string` were to return a mutable `char*`, that would imply that you can treat that `char*` as a valid C-string and perform C-string operations like `strcpy`, that would easily turn to undefined behavior were the string not allocated contiguously.

The C++11 standard added the rule that `basic_string` has to be implemented as a contiguous byte array. Needless to say, you can work-around this by using the old trick of `&str[0]`.

Comment: I would go further and say that to provide a mutable `data()` method would defeat the encapsulation of the `string` object by encouraging developers to use it as a byte buffer. It would therefore be a retrograde step.

Comment: You say it comes from the pre-C++11 restriction, but since `string::data` was introduced as part of the C++11, where and the contiguous requirement was already in place, why not also provide `char* string::data()` as a part of C++11?

Comment: according to here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/data/ `std::string::data` already had being exist since C++98. it also speaks of the same issue I was presenting here.

Comment: @RichardHodges I don't believe that the standard committee agrees with you sir, as they have provided `data()` on `array`, `dynarray`, and `vector` without fear of "retrograde", so I don't think that was a motivation.

Comment: @DavidHaim Interesting, so it existed, but I was just unaware of it, and now that `data` exists in a mutable format elsewhere, I'm no longer happy with `string` providing the same thing it always has.

Comment: why do you want `data` anyway? perhapse there are better ways of doing the thing you want

Comment: @JonathanMee I'm sure there is much that the committee would disagree with me on. In many cases I'm sure that's a good thing :-)
I suppose at least the method `data()` explicitly expresses intent, whereas `&s[0]` is cryptic. So ok, I'm persuaded.

Comment: @DavidHaim I think the only time you'd want to legitimately use mutable `data()` is when using the string to provide a buffer to receive data from an external 'c'-style library AND you subsequently wanted to use that data as a string.

Comment: @RichardHodges I'm sad to report that there are even [times when `sprintf` is required](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25429632/2642059). And I'd much rather be calling `fullfloat.data()` here than `&*fullfloat.begin()`. So I think even your "external 'c'-style" stipulation may be too broad. I might just need this functionality internally.

Comment: @JonathanMee if there's ostream functionality missing because of the lack of an appropriate manipulator, isn't it better to fix the standard so that it provides one? It seems to me that emitting formatted data into a stream can be achieved in a more encapsulated way than resorting to the landmine that is `sprintf` in mainline code. As an implementation detail of a custom utility function it's more forgivable, IMHO.

Comment: @RichardHodges I agree with that sentiment. Fix the real problem with `ostream` don't just obscure it. But it doesn't stop me from wanting `char* string::data()` too :D

Comment: @JonathanMee on balance, I agree with you. The provision of a mutable `data()` would be less cryptic than hacking it with `&s[0]` or `addressof(*begin(s))`. I think we just made history. I just changed my view in public on the internet :-))

Comment: @RichardHodges I've given you a random +1 that was just too funny. lol

Comment: C++17 has added a non-const `data()` member to `string`.