# Reading contents of file into dynamically allocated char* array- can I read into std::string instead?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11

I have found myself writing code which looks like this

```
// Treat the following as pseudocode - just an example

iofile.seekg(0, std::ios::end); // iofile is a file opened for read/write
uint64_t f_len = iofile.tellg();

if(f_len >= some_min_length)
{
    // Focus on the following code here
    char *buf = new char[7];
    char buf2[]{"MYFILET"}; // just some random string
                            // if we see this it's a good indication
                            // the rest of the file will be in the
                            // expected format (unlikely to see this
                            // sequence in a "random file", but don't
                            // worry too much about this)
    iofile.read(buf, 7);

    if(memcmp(buf, buf2, 7) == 0) // I am confident this works
    {
        // carry on processing file ...
        // ...
        // ...
    }
}
else
    cout << "invalid file format" << endl;
```

This code is probably an okay sketch of what we might want to do when opening a file, which has some specified format (which I've dictated). We do some initial check to make sure the string `"MYFILET"` is at the start of the file - because I've decided all my files for the job I'm doing are going to start with this sequence of characters.

I think this code would be better if we didn't have to play around with "c-style" character arrays, but used strings everywhere instead. **This would be advantageous** because we could do things like `if(buf == buf2)` if `buf` and `buf2` where `std::string`s.

A possible alternative could be,

```
// Focus on the following code here
std::string buf;
std::string buf2("MYFILET"); // very nice
buf.resize(7); // okay, but not great
iofile.read(buf.data(), 7); // pretty awful - error prone if wrong length argument given
                            // also we have to resize buf to 7 in the previous step
                            // lots of potential for mistakes here,
                            // and the length was used twice which is never good
if(buf == buf2) then do something
```

What are the problems with this?

- We had to use the length variable `7` (or constant in this case) twice. Which is somewhere between "not ideal" and "potentially error prone".
- We had to access the contents of `buf` using `.data()` which I shall assume here is implemented to return a raw pointer of some sort. *I don't personally mind this too much*, but others may prefer a more memory-safe solution, perhaps hinting we should use an iterator of some sort? I think in Visual Studio (for Windows users which I am not) then this may return an iterator anyway, which will give [?] warnings/errors [?] - not sure on this.
- We had to have an additional resize statement for `buf`. It would be better if the size of `buf` could be automatically set somehow.

Answer (score 2):

It is undefined behavior to write into the `const char*` returned by `std::string::data()`.  However, you are free to use `std::vector::data()` in this way.

If you want to use std::string, and dislike setting the size yourself, you may consider whether you can use `std::getline()`.  This is the free function, not `std::istream::getline()`.  The `std::string` version will read up to a specified delimiter, so if you have a text format you can tell it to read until `'\0'` or some other character which will never occur, and it will automatically resize the given string to hold the contents.

If your file is binary in nature, rather than text, I think most people would find `std::vector<char>` to be a more natural fit than `std::string` anyway.

Comment: `std::string::data()` returns `char *` not `const char *`

Comment: @Slava: No, it really does return `const char*` until C++17 (which is not released yet and most people aren't using).  For more, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34155390/why-doesnt-stdstring-data-provide-a-mutable-char

Comment: I deffo can't use anything as high level as `getline`

Comment: Does `std::vector<char>` have an `operator==`? I thought not?

Comment: @JohnZwinck I see, c++ is a bigger mess than I thought

Comment: @user3728501: Yes vector==vector exists: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp

Answer (score 1):

> We had to use the length variable 7 (or constant in this case) twice.
>   Which is somewhere between "not ideal" and "potentially error prone".

The second time you can use `buf.size()`

```
iofile.read(buf.data(), buf.size());
```

> We had to access the contents of buf using .data() which I shall
>   assume here is implemented to return a raw pointer of some sort.

And pointed by John Zwinck, `.data()` return a pointer to `const`.

I suppose you could define `buf` as `std::vector<char>`; for `vector` (if I'm not wrong) `.data()` return a pointer to `char` (in this case), not to `const char`.

`size()` and `resize()` are working in the same way.

> We had to have an additional resize statement for buf. It would be
>   better if the size of buf could be automatically set somehow.

I don't think `read()` permit this.

p.s.: sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

```
template<class Src>
std::string read_string( Src& src, std::size_t count){
  std::string buf;
  buf.resize(count);
  src.read(&buf.front(), 7); // in C++17 make it buf.data()
  return buf;
}
```

Now `auto read = read_string( iofile, 7 );` is clean at point of use.

`buf2` is a bad plan.  I'd do:

```
if(read=="MYFILET")
```

directly, or use a `const char myfile_magic[] = "MYFILET";`.

Comment: While I agree that removing the local `buf2` is a good idea if it is to be used only once, I would suggest `if(read == std::string("MYFILET"))` is even better?

Comment: I don't understand the line `const char myfile_magic = "MYFILET"` - is this supposed to be `const char myfile_magic[]{"MYFILET"}`?

Comment: @user missed a `[]`, yes.  Manually converting to `std::string` is a pessimization.

Comment: What do you think about the above comments and undefined behaviour?

Comment: @user C++17 has a non-const `data` on `std::string`.  If it works, your compiler is forward looking.  Writing to `&str.front()` is legal and well defined, up to `str.size()`.

Comment: I think both `front` and `data` return `const char*`? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data |||| http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/front

Comment: @user there are two `front` overloads in C++11.  There is one `data` in 11, then two in 17.

Answer (score 0):

We can validate a signature without double buffering (rdbuf and a string) and allocating from the heap...

```
// terminating null not included
constexpr char sig[] = { 'M', 'Y', 'F', 'I', 'L', 'E', 'T' };     
auto ok = all_of(begin(sig), end(sig), [&fs](char c) { return fs.get() == (int)c; });
if (ok) {}
```

Comment: Yes it is an `fstream` - why is this important?

Comment: Removed assumption statement. Thanks

Comment: No it's okay you can leave it - I'm just wondering what else you think it could be, and why that would/would not work?

Answer (score 0):

I liked many of the ideas from the examples above, however I wasn't completely satisfied that there was an answer which would produce undefined-behaviour-free code for C++11 and C++17. I currently write most of my code in C++11 - because I don't anticipate using it on a machine *in the future* which doesn't have a C++11 compiler.

If one doesn't, then I add a new compiler or change machines.

However it *does seem to me to be a bad idea to write code which I know may not work under C++17*... That's just my personal opinion. I don't anticipate using this code again, but I don't want to create a potential problem for myself in the future.

Therefore I have come up with the following code. **I hope other users will give feedback to help improve this.** (For example there is no error checking yet.)

```
std::string
fstream_read_string(std::fstream& src, std::size_t n)
{
    char *const buffer = new char[n + 1];
    src.read(buffer, n);
    buffer[n] = '\0';
    std::string ret(buffer);
    delete [] buffer;
    return ret;
}
```

This seems like a basic, probably fool-proof method... It's a shame there seems to be no way to get std::string to use the same memory as allocated  by the call to `new`.

Note we had to add an extra trailing null character in the C-style string, which is sliced off in the C++-style `std::string`.