# Usage of string::c_str() and data() under pre-C++11 standards

Tags: c++, memory, undefined-behavior

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34155390), an internal buffer of `std::string` is not guaranteed to be contiguous under pre-C++11 standards. (Albeit almost all implementations use contiguous memory)

This means, technically, accessing a nth(n > 0?) element of a return value of `string::data()` or `string::c_str()` causes an undefined behavior. Is this correct?

```
std::string str = "Hello, World!"
str.c_str()[1]; // Which is equivalent to *(str.c_str() + 1), therefore UB?
```

Comment: It's impossible to return non-contiguous memory with `const char *`. So no not really.

Comment: The c_str() was not required to return a pointer to internal buffer. That is why it was const.

Comment: @rustyx Why is it impossible?

Comment: an aside, pre c++11, `data()` didn't have to be null-terminated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, since the specification of C++98 clearly states what you get: An contiguous array of characters.

The internal implementation of the string storage is not necessarily reflected in method results. If the string is not stored in one part, the methods have to make sure, that you get what you want. This could mean, that the whole content is copied in a different place.

That is the reason, why you should not alter the string representation you get.

You and the person implementing the methods must both read carefully the standard describing what you get.

Answer (score 0):

`str.c_str()[...];` is fine, so long as you don't run off the end of the string.  After all, it's a C string so what else would you expect?

As for `str.data()`, [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) has this to say:

> `const CharT* data() const` returns a pointer to the underlying array serving as character storage. The pointer is such that the range [data(); data() + size()) is valid and the values in it correspond to the values stored in the string.

Now I don't know if this is entirely trustworthy, but cppreference does not qualify that statement as applying to any particular version of the standard. But, probably, it should do.

Comment: The C++98 standard said *"a pointer to the initial element of an array whose first `size()` elements equal the corresponding elements of the string"*. So could *theoretically* be a separate buffer. But it never was, so the C++11 change was just documenting existing practice.

Comment: @BoPersson Right, thanks.  Makes sense.  So what cppreference has to say can be relied on then, even before C++11.